# How does the AI act, depending on each difficulty? Is there a special way they do things?

Tags: civilization-3

I'm a new player at Civilization 3, and I want to know how the other countries/civilizations will act. Is there a reason they will move the way they do? Is there any special thing to watch out for? How does the AI change when you select different difficulties? There should be a certain way that you will be able to react the the AI so you can get better games? Depending on the difficulty, will the game last a bit less, because it's more difficult to stay alive?

Comment: If what the [fandom wiki](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Difficulty_level_(Civ3)) says is true for Civ 3: "*Since the computer players are not controlled by advanced AI (i.e. **cannot learn from and react to the player's strategies by changing their own accordingly**), but instead behave based on a very long list of if-then statements, the game makes the AI leaders more challenging opponents by giving them advantages on higher difficulty levels.*" Each game version page states this though.  I'd hate to manage that list of `if-else` statements...

Comment: This channel is very active and has a long catalog of Civ 3 videos: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvJNJ8HF5BWrErL-RpvqbYQ/videos
I suggest you check it out as it's very helpful to understanding the game